# Why get_event_loop Cannot Be Used With run_in_executor

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Could anyone tell why the code below

```
import asyncio
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

ASYNC_INTERVAL = 0.1

def plain_hello_world(name):
    s = "Hello world "+str(name)
    print(s)
    return s

def plain_loop(name, t):
    start_time = time.time()
    prev_time = start_time
    while (time.time() - start_time < t):
        if time.time() - prev_time > ASYNC_INTERVAL:
            prev_time = time.time()
            plain_hello_world(name)

def task1():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.run_in_executor(None, plain_loop, "func", 1)
    loop.run_until_complete(task)

def task2():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.run_in_executor(None, task1)
    loop.run_until_complete(task)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    task2()
```

gets error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyncio_practice4.py", line 28, in <module>
    task2()
  File "asyncio_practice4.py", line 25, in task2
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "asyncio_practice4.py", line 18, in task1
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 694, in get_event_loop
    return get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 602, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.
```

**Question:**

I do not understand why such error occurs.

Running `task1()` only is fine, but along with one another `run_in_executor()` it says no current evet loop. (But I think it should, I did not create a new thread)

Does anyone know what is going on?

And how to fix it assuming we can only work on `task2()`?

**Note:**

The reason to call 2 `run_in_executor()` is because code above is mimicking integrating a 3rd lib into asyncio code.

`plain_hello_world()`, `plain_loop()`, and `task1()` are codes in lib, which I cannot modify.

Assuming `task1()` runs for 100s and I do not want to wait for it, so I try to run it in executor as how other plain functions work with asyncio.

**Edit:**
Based on the answer, here is the revision that works:

```
def task2():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    def wrapper():
        asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
        task1()
    task = loop.run_in_executor(None, wrapper)
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

Though I am not sure how "correct" or good it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not understand why such error occurs.

It occurs because `task1` assumes that it will run in either the main thread (where `get_event_loop()` creates an event loop on-demand) or in a thread where `set_event_loop` was previously called to set up an event loop. Since `run_in_executor` invokes its function in a thread other than the main thread, and your code doesn't call `set_event_loop()` before invoking it, you get the error.

> Assuming task1() runs for 100s and I do not want to wait for it, so I try to run it in executor as how other plain functions work with asyncio.

Running a sync function and not waiting for it is not something you do with asyncio, it's a job for regular threads. For example:

```py
def task1_bg():
    def work():
        asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
        task1()
    threading.Thread(target=work).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    task1_bg()
    # do something else...
```

Comment: I see, thanks. Is thread the only resort for sync functions? I thought run_in_executor() is the one to deal with those sync functions, and asyncio is a better substitute of thread (maybe I am wrong, though)

Comment: @adayoegi `run_in_executor` is for an async code base. Asyncio is not a "substitute" for threads, it is a completely different approach. If your code base is already asyncio, you should be able to run the event loop, which `task1` apparently doesn't let you do.

Comment: Thank you. I made a revision in edit. Do you think it makes sense?

Comment: @adayoegi I am confused by your edit. That `task2` implementation is clearly **waiting** for `task1` to finish (because of `run_until_complete`). How is that while thing different than just calling `task1()` directly?

Comment: The result is same if we only have task1(), but is different if we have more than that. `run_until_complete()` is what I want here (it is a minimal example here, in real application it can be some functions calling task2(), while task2() itself is also async)

Comment: Deeply thanks to your detailed explanation, though I did not apply your thread solution in the end, it inspires me a lot. I just got wanted behavior with the same method in my edit

Comment: @adayoegi It should be possible to only use one event loop for everything. If the other things you do are actually asyncio-related, that changes things. - I was under the impression that you wanted `task1` to run "in the background" and get on with your blocking (non-asyncio) code. What do you think of [this approach](https://pastebin.com/3KHnZVnr) to integrate your asyncio code and that of `task1`?

Comment: Thanks for the effort, the example achieves concurrent works. However, it does not fit my shoes. Since it is stackoverflow here, I posted minimal example to reproduce my problem, which is integrating a 3rd lib using `get_event_loop()`. In my real application, there are 10~20 tasks with different sources. Some are made by myself while some are other people's work. Besides, for those 20 tasks, their order matters. Some must be done before others, while some should be run at the same time. For all of these tasks, I need to provide a general API to wrap them, no matter they are async func or not.

Comment: So, `run_until_complete()` here is served as a outside command make sure the tasks are run, not to mean that I want to wait for it. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: @adayoegi Fair enough, the only problem is that your minimal example was _too_ minimal, in that it didn't capture the essence of the problem. With the situation as you describe it, your approach probalby makes sense. Having multiple independent event loops is definitely _possible_, it just shouldn't (normally) be _necessary_.